# SD Card not available while on USB Debugging Mode on DroidX

Tags: android, usb, sd-card

I am working on Camera/Video application @ work. When I turn on the usb-debugging mode on my droidX it appears that the Camera application cannot access the SD Card on the device. If I choose another USB connection mode, SD card is available but then I cannot debug the application.

I am working on a droidX on Macbook Pro machine.

Comment: Have you checked whether USB Mass Storage is turned on ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the usb connection from "mass storage" to "Charge Only"

You should be able to debug in that mode. If not, something else is wrong.